# How to set these system variables to allow for emoji in google cloud mysql?

Tags: mysql, cloud, google-cloud-sql

I have followed the instructions here
https://medium.com/google-cloud/enable-full-unicode-in-mysql-on-google-cloud-aaa2635486d6

But I can't see flags to set for these variables

```
SET character_set_client = 'utf8mb4';
SET character_set_connection = 'utf8mb4';
SET character_set_results = 'utf8mb4';
```

I can set them in the session, and emoji can be read and written. 
Is there a way to set them for system or for the specific db?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the server side character set by following the instructions for [Configuring database flags](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags) to set `character_set_server`.

You can also ste character set in the `CREATE` or `ALTER` statements for an individual [database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-database.html), [table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-table.html) or even [column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-column.html).

Comment: Perhaps a more direct way of asking my question is... How do I set character_set_client, character_set_connection, and character_set_results globally since they don't show up in the google cloud db flags interface?

Comment: They cannot be set on a Cloud SQL server. They aren't usually needed though, especially if your client is also configured to utf8mb4 (which you will need anyway if you want to send/receive emojis.)

Comment: Good point. The client I use is MySQLWorkbench. I typically interface with the database from automation workflows using zapier. Do you have any recommendations for this setup?